# How can I connect to my Apache 2 web site that sits on the Ubuntu Server through IP?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-virtualhost

Here's my virtual host configurations:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName abwebserver
    ServerAdmin <my e-mail>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mediawiki
    AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/?abwiki(/.*)?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.php [L]

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/mediawiki_error
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/mediawiki_access common
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm to trying connect to my web site from the other Windows 10 machine that's on the network like this:

```
http://<IP address>/abwiki/
```

but it doesn't work.

If I put the `<IP address> abwebserver` line to the *hosts* file then it works.

What changes should I make to my configuration files in order to be able to connect to the web site through the IP?

I already tried disabling `000-default.conf` in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`, so only my web site is there. I also tried changing `<VirtualHost *:80>` to `<VirtualHost [IP_Address]:80>`, but it didn't help.

Comment: What does it exactly mean that the site does not work? Do you get some Apache error message or maybe your MediaWiki software cannot properly handle the site if you use an IP address and not a domain name (it is quite common issue with CMSes)? Do you see the request in your Apache logs specified in the config (`CustomLog` or `ErrorLog`) if you access the site via IP address? Does access via IP address to a simple HTML file that you placed in the `/var/www/mediawiki` directory work?

Comment: When I placed some HTML file into the `/var/www/mediawiki` directory and typed `http://<IP_address>/random.html` it worked. But when I type `http://<IP_Address>` or `http://<IP_Address>/abwiki/` I can see that it's substituting my `<IP_Adress>` for its `ServerName` which is `abwebserver`, so it's trying to connect to the `http://abwebserver/Main_Page` but fails, because I don't a DNS record and haven't added anything in my hosts file. I just want to type the IP and connect to my web site.

Comment: If access to HTML file works, the problem is in your MediaWiki software, not in Apache config. Your MediaWiki software is redirecting requests to `http://<IP_Address>` to `http://abwebserver` . As I wrote, it is common in CMS-type software. You have to check the MediaWiki documentation if this redirect can be turned off. I can't help you with that, as I don't know this software.

Comment: You actually did help me! It was the `/var/www/mediawiki/LocalSettings.php` file where all MediaWiki settings reside. I changed `$wgServer = "http://abwebserver"` to `$wgServer = "http://<IP_address>"` and now it works! I just thought that it was the Apache problem.